# How to convert speech mark offset into time

Tags: unity-game-engine, amazon-polly

Amazon polly provides speech marks with text.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/polly/latest/dg/using-speechmarks.html

It says

start – the offset in bytes (not characters) of the start of the object in the input text (not including viseme marks)

How can I convert this "start" into a starting position in time to begin reading from there for instance with Unity?

Answer (score 0):

You would have to use the `time` attribute to get the time offset at which the object is spoken. That is, from the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/polly/latest/dg/using-speechmarks.html#output):

> ***time*** – the timestamp in milliseconds from the beginning of the corresponding audio stream